Old, sci-fi like, short movie, alien looks down on earth from space
I'm looking for this funny, sci-fi like, stop-motion movie which I saw approximately 40+ years ago. The movie could be much older.
I think it is black and white, but I could be wrong.
Unfortunately, I have no idea which country it is from.
It starts with a bird-like looking alien coming to earth (it stays in orbit and doesn't land, and it flies on its own. No spaceship), and begins to look down on the planet.
Here is what it see:
Humans are represented by beans, and they are using normal household things, only for complete other purposes than we would. For example they are driving around in tin cans (the flat ones, that sardines come in) as they use them for cars.
At some point two beans try to rob something (a giant necklace they are pulling out of a house), they drag it over a comb, lying with the teeth pointing upwards, resembling a fence with spikes. Another bean who acts like a guard, fires at the thieves using a match; the phosphor lights up like when ignited normally, but one of the beans is wounded.
A lot more hilarious things happen, but I don't remember much more.
The movie ends with the beans being aware of the alien in the sky, and they get annoyed by its presence. They launch a rocket that flies up to the alien hitting it, and the alien escapes making a sound like when you enter a hen house and scare all the chickens.
There is no talking, only some background music.
Does anybody recognize this?

I luckily found this myself, after some googling.
It's Scenes with Beans, directed by Ottó Foky



